# A Google script to disable keys in a keyboard

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a project in which the "Delete" key needs to be disabled in keyboard when working on the sheet. Is there a script to do this?

Comment: thanks for the response. unfortunately, our company prohibit us using 3rd party apps except for google sheets, macros are disabled and discouraged by our IT team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script can't disable keys in a keyboard.

The above is based on official documentation as it doesn't include any service to  modify the key behavior.